# Master Mode on Intel 5100

Tags: linux, wifi, intel

Is it possible to enable wireless master mode on Intel 5100 wireless cards? They use the iwlagn driver and that does not seem to support master mode. Is there any way to change the driver or recompile it so as to support master mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that this is for your hostAP setup. If it is not supported, your best bet would be to buy a new card that supports it.

Comment: Okay. I have another laptop with a broadcom4311 which I think is supported but I can't seem to get it to work. I'll try some more and then get back to serverfault (or someplace else, as it's not exactly a question-answer issue). Thanks!